# How are Windows services created using Chef?

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I have a jar file I'd like to run as a service on Windows, but I don't believe creating a Windows service is supported in Chef: [CHEF-3865](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3865)

How are Chef users adding new services to Windows machines they manage? Powershell?

My jar file is for the Jenkins Swarm Plugin, I am dynamically creating new swarm slaves using Chef.

Comment: Are you using the Windows cookbook?

Comment: Hi Seth, I looked in there, is there a way to wrap a jar file and install it as a service? If not, I think I have WinSW working: https://kenai.com/projects/winsw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using WinSW w/ a new Chef Cookbook.

Cookbook Steps:

1. Download jar to node.
2. Download winsw wrapper app to node.
3. Download winsw config file to node.
4. Update the winsw config file with node-specific info (jar to install, etc)
5. Install the jar service wrapper: winsw.exe install (returns 0 if successful, 23 if already installed).