# Determining a Windows Service is installed using Chef

Tags: windows, service, chef-infra

What is the correct/preferred way to determine whether a given service is installed on a Windows machine when using Chef?

I am using the service resource to manage starting and stopping the service, but I see no way to determine if a service is installed (my service doesn't show up in the Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs menu and has no registry entries).

I need to determine if my service is installed to ensure my recipe is idempotent.

Comment: Are you saying the `service` resource isn't handling this for you. The `service` resource is idempotent...

Comment: Hi (again) Seth, are you saying that if I attempt to start a non-existent service in my recipe, that's okay? This is somewhat related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096451/how-are-windows-services-created-using-chef. I need to create a windows service to wrap/run a jar file.